# Use of singleton in IOS and things to watch out for

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton

I have been using singleton quite extensively to interact with firebase similar to the following class. I find singleton very handy so I wanted to get abit more insight into it before I start over using it. One of the instructor from an online course mentioned that I have to be very careful about using singleton but he didn't really explain why. I'd like to know how I can use it correctly and why is it that I need to be very careful about using them?

```
class DataService {
static let dataService = DataService()

private var _BASE_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)")
private var _USER_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)/users")
private var _JOKE_REF = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)/jokes")

var BASE_REF: Firebase {
    return _BASE_REF
}

var USER_REF: Firebase {
    return _USER_REF
}

var CURRENT_USER_REF: Firebase {
    let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String

    let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_REF)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(userID)

    return currentUser!
}

var JOKE_REF: Firebase {
    return _JOKE_REF
}
```

Also, I am also going to create another singleton as shown below (I have not yet create as I want to understand it a bit better first). These "posts" will be accessed by multiple VC's, that is why I wanted to use a singleton so that all of the VC can access whichever array they need without creating any conflict. In general terms, is there anything that I need to watch out with this sort of setup?

Sorry the question might be a bit broad. But the idea is to get an overview of what to watch out with using Singleton in these specific examples (memory, allocation, timing??)

```
class PostService {

static let ps = PostService()

private var _myPosts = [Post]()
private var _otherPeoplesPosts = [Post]()
private var _followingPosts = [Post]()

var myPosts: [Post] {
    return _myPosts

}

var otherPeoplesPosts: [Post] {
    return _otherPeoplesPosts
}

var followingPosts: [Post] {
    return _followingPosts
}
```

Comment: If the point of the singleton is simply to persist data, there's better alternative like core data if you can use them. If you can pass the data into the view controller instead of using a singleton that is better as well.

As for memory management it's safe. Memory leaks wont happen if you reset properties and your objects don't hold a reference to the singleton.

From my experience i have only used singletons when i had some sort of continuous running task or a service such as image caching where every class may use it and benefit (UIView, UIViewController, any model class/struct, etc)

Comment: The image cache isn't even the best example because i could create instances of the image cache and pass them to where they need to be.

Comment: "Singleton carry state around for the lifetime of the app". Does that mean the life time of the app on the phone or the life time of the app before it gets closed (foreground and background).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only main issue regarding singletons is the fact that they remain in memory whether you use them or not.

Your first singleton looks like it could easily be replaced with a struct with static functions.

As mentioned in one of the comments, using some sort of storage (i.e CoreData) would be better as the objects aren't in the heap (at least not all of them). 
If your arrays consists of several dozens of objects it shouldn't be a problem, but imagine that every array holds hundreds of objects.
Sure, it'll be accessible from everywhere in the app but the downside is your memory usage will be very high.

If you don't use CoreData and it's going to be a problem for you to integrate it in your project, consider storing the data to the documents folder and limit the number of objects in memory and when you need to access an object which is not in the array, load it from the documents folder and replace the last used object (Kinda like CoreData does). It's not ideal and will require some intense logic, but it's better than having too many objects in the heap and cause a memory warning.

Bottom line, it depends on the usage and the size of your data.

Hope it helps in some way.